# Python - Open a given path in a separate window and continue script

Tags: python, ubuntu, window, subprocess

My question is how can I open a given path in a window and continue the script? I'd also like to select where to put that window.

This is aimed to Ubuntu, where I can set a window in any corner by pressing cntrl + alt + 1/7/9/3.

I've tried this so far, but appart from not being able to continue the script, I can't select where to position the window:

`import subprocess`
`subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", "/home/user/Desktop"])`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The window placement is performed according to the placement policy of ones user interface. This can be influenced by add-ons, but depends on the user interface you use.

As to the continuation of the script, you could call the subprocess.Popen(...) in a thread you create for that purpose.